# Stop animation loop

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

How do I stop animation loop on click in jQuery?
The following code generates blinking effect on the input field and works fine:

```
function blink() {
    $('#client_name').animate({"border-color": "#00DB00"}, 400);
    $('#client_name').animate({"border-color": "#ccc"}, 400);
}

setInterval(blink, 1000);
```

I tried `stop()` but it stops only currently running animation, not the whole loop:

```
$('#client_surname').click(function() {
    $('#client_name').stop();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval).

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) returns intervalID, a unique interval ID you can pass to clearInterval()

```
var interval = setInterval(blink,1000);

$('#client_surname').click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var timer = setInterval(blink,1000);

$('#client_surname').click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```